# R: T-test giving me strange results. Null hypothesis always rejected

Tags: r, t-test

Here is my r code and the output of the t-test. Even if the mean is clearly 0, the t-test still accepts the alternative hypothesis.

```
> x = c(-2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
> t.test(x, alternative="two.sided")

One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 0, df = 17, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.6606089  0.6606089
sample estimates:
mean of x 
        0
```

Similarly if I run the code on different vector.

```
> x = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
> t.test(x, alternative="two.sided")

    One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 12.1214, df = 17, p-value = 8.625e-10
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.009486 1.434958
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 1.222222
```

Here I would be expecting to see: `alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 0`, but it only happens if I put the `alternative` parameter to `"greater"`.

I feel like this is a very basic misunderstanding of how the t-test works in R.

Comment: Welcome to our site! Thanks for providing your complete code, and so making your example reproducible. It turns out that your issue is really about understanding R output rather than understanding statistical content *per se* (so some might argue this belongs on Stack Overflow), but since other searchers might look here first to work out what's going on, I think there is a place for it on Cross Validated.

Comment: If you'd typed `?t.test` (or [looked at the help online](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/t.test.html)) you'd see that `alternative` is "a character string describing the alternative hypothesis" rather than the decision the test comes to. Probably a good idea if you're not sure what's going on.

Comment: @Silverfish At the topic of statistics. I am using this t-test to determine if answers to questionnaire (answers are on 5-point Likert scale) are statistically significant towards either "Agree" or "Disagree". n = 18. What is appropriate significance level for my t-test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line where it says `alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0` is **not** the result of the test! Instead, it simply restates what the alternative hypothesis is. It is upon you to decide, based on the `p-value`, whether you reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis.

In your first example, you fail to reject the null (`p-value = 1`), meaning the true mean of the underlying population you are sampling from **is not** significantly different from zero.

In your second example your `p-value = 8.625e-10` and you reject the null concluding that true mean of the underlying population you are sampling from **is** significantly different from zero.